# Insert null object to objects of array javascript

Tags: javascript

i have an array :

```
let data = {
 {date: 3, type: solid; total: 3},
 {date: 5, type: solid; total: 10}
}
```

is it possible to convert it into new array with output like this :

```
data: {
0: {date: 1, type: solid; total: null},
1: {date: 2, type: solid; total: null},
2: {date: 3, type: solid; total: 3},
3: {date: 4, type: solid; total: null},
4: {date: 5, type: solid; total: 10},
5: {date: 6, type: solid; total: null},
6: {date: 7, type: solid; total: null},
....
27: {date: 28, type: solid; total: null},
28: {date: 29, type: solid; total: null},
29: {date: 30, type: solid; total: null},
30: {date: 31, type: solid; total: null}
}
```

i want the length of new array is same as the total date of current month
thanks before

Comment: Your code is not showing an array, but rather an object using numbers as keys.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, in case you wonder why you are being downvoted, you should check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . As for your question, I think you should check the [difference between arrays and objects](https://dev.to/zac_heisey/objects-vs-arrays-2g0e).

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is an object, I assume it's an array, and the code should look like :

```js
const daysOfMonth = new Date(Date.UTC(new Date().getUTCFullYear(), new Date().getUTCMonth() + 1, 0)).getDate()
const data = [{
    date: 3,
    type: 'solid',
    total: 3
  },
  {
    date: 5,
    type: 'solid',
    total: 10
  }
]
const result = []
const resultObject = {}
for(let i = 0; i < daysOfMonth; i++) {
  let exist = data.find(el => el.date === i)
  if(exist) {
    result[i] = {...exist}
    resultObject[i] = {...exist}
  } else {
    result[i] = {date: i, type: 'solid', total: null}
    resultObject[i] = {date: i, type: 'solid', total: null}
  }
}
console.log('Array : ', result)
console.log('Object : ', resultObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
let data = [
  { date: 3, type: "solid", total: 3 },
  { date: 5, type: "solid", total: 10 },
];

//get current month date
let now = new Date();
let dateCount = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();

let text = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= dateCount; i++) {
  let filterData = data.filter((data) => data.date === i);
  if (filterData.length > 0) {
    text.push(filterData[0]);
  } else {
    let tempObj = { date: i, type: "solid", total: null };
    text.push(tempObj);
  }
}
console.log("text=>", text);
```